# Preventing SQL injection on insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

I am looking for some tips to prevent SQL injection. I was told on a forum my code is not safe and am looking for someone nice enough to help me fix that.

I have a webform and on submit it goes to the aspx.cs page and inserts the data into a ms sql database.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FullStartTime = StartTimeHourList.SelectedValue + ":" + StartTimeMinuteList.SelectedValue + " " + StartTimeAMList.SelectedValue;
        string FullEndTime = EndTimeHourList.SelectedValue + ":" + EndTimeMinuteList.SelectedValue + " " + EndTimeAMList.SelectedValue;

        OleDbConnection conn;
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("");
        cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        var sql = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO FormTable1 (Nonprofit, Contact, Phone, Email, Event, StartDate, EndDate, StartTime, EndTime, Place, Comments, SubmitDate) values 
                                                            ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')",
                                                           NonprofitTxtBox.Text, ContactTxtBox.Text, PhoneTxtBox.Text, EmailTxtBox.Text, EventTxtBox.Text,
                                                           StartDateTxtBox.Text, EndDateTxtBox.Text, FullStartTime, FullEndTime, PlaceTxtBox.Text, CommentsTxtBox.Text, DateTime.Now);
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
 }
```

Comment: you're directly embedding external data into your queries. You need to use prepared statements with placeholders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: If you can't find any information on preventing SQL injection in c# on the internet, you need a new profession.

Comment: @BradM When did I say this was a profession?

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc the link was very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward fix is to simply **not** build sql by concatenating strings together, and instead using params.  If you're using SqlCommand you can do the following, otherwise do as @MarcB suggested

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT dbo.Table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (@f1, @f2, @f3)", conn);

cmd.Paramters.Add("@f1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "abc";
cmd.Paramters.Add("@f2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
cmd.Paramters.Add("@f3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "some other value";
```

Comment: @kcray I don't think that the OleDBCommand supports naming your parameters.  If you run into trouble, try replacing the parameters in the insert statement with question marks: INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) values (?, ?), and leave out the name on parameters.Add.  Better still, if you don't really need OleDb, switch to the SqlConnection and SqlCommand in System.Data.SqlClient (only works for an ms sql database), and then you can use the named parameters as Jason did above.

Comment: @JMarsch good catch, too bad it doesn't support it, I've updated the answer to clear up any confusion, this should be for sql command

Comment: @Jason Yah, I always kind of wished that there had been a tighter spec on parameter names (oracle supports named params, but uses colons as delimiters instead of at signs, oledb doesn't support named params at all, etc) -- we ended up writing our own wrapper around parameters to enforce named params using at signs as delimiters (of course these days, I mostly use EF anyway)