# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

I am new as `C#` programmer and I wrote a code while following a tutorial on youtube and I would like to improve it by adding features.

However, when I run the program, I keep getting an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

The inner exception is:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

I checked and the code seems correct to me.

I doublechecked all columns in Access file and all the columns are correctly spelled.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace Biletotomasyon
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        OleDbConnection baglanti=new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/msi-nb/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Biletotomasyon/YOLCU.accdb");


        private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox7_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button56_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            baglanti.Open();
            OleDbCommand komut=new OleDbCommand ("INSERT INTO YOLCU (SEFER SAYISI,GÜZERGAH,VARİŞ YERİ,TARİH,SAAT,PERON,AD SOYAD,KOLTUKNO,TAM BİLET ÜCRETİ,TC,IB SAYISI,TOPLAM ÜCRET,CİNSİYET,BİLET CİNSİ) values ('"+comboBox7.Text.ToString()+"','"+comboBox6.Text.ToString()+"','"+comboBox1.Text.ToString()+"','"+ dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString()+"','"+comboBox5.Text.ToString()+"','"+comboBox2.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox1.Text.ToString()+"','"+comboBox4.Text.ToString()+"','"+comboBox3.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox2.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox3.Text.ToString()+"',,'"+textBox4.Text.ToString()+"','"+radioButton1.Text.ToString()+"','"+radioButton3.Text.ToString()+"')",baglanti);
            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            baglanti.Close();


        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: You have two commas next to each other. `,,` Remove one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing SQL injection on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818473/preventing-sql-injection-on-insert)

Answer (score 1):

That's cause you have columns which have white space like `TOPLAM ÜCRET,BİLET CİNSİ` that needs to be escaped like `"TOPLAM ÜCRET"` or if using MS Access then `[TOPLAM ÜCRET]`

Comment: l deleted whitespaces from both Access and code ,however ,still the problem is on table.l deleted one commas ,as mjwill said.

Comment: after l corrected all according to suggestion , l got new error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''2017-1-01AB2013,'ADANA','ANKARA','Tuesday'." l could not find where the missing operatör.