# How to insert null values in Ms access using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

i just add value like this  Mc access column data type (text,numeric-double,text,numeric-percentage)
    but i insert this values(john,"","","")this one value value not inserted
this error
because i have only name list
help me

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in biodata.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      con.Open();
       cmd.CommandText = "insert into hhh (name,answerinfloat,subject,avg)VALUES('" + a.Text + "','" + b.Text + "','" + c.Text + "','" + d.Text + "')";

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", a.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("answerinfloat", b.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("subject", c.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("avg", d.Text);



        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        if (n > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Submitted", "Congrats");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("insertion failed");

   con.Close();
```

}

Comment: If you omit the column names in the query text then you need to provide values for all the columns present in your table. Just add the name of the columns and look at what is an Sql Injection hack. Your code is ready to be hacked.

Comment: I would highly recommend you look in to [Parameterizing your query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: **warning:** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. don't use string concat. use parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing SQL injection on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818473/preventing-sql-injection-on-insert)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the columns you are inserting into:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into hhh (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES('" + a.Text + "','" + b.Text + "','" + c.Text + "','" + d.Text + "')";
```

Just replace col1, col2 etc. with the actual names of the columns you wish to insert into.  The columns you omit will not get a value, and will become NULL (provided that they in fact allow NULLs)

As the others have commented, you should look into using parameterized queries instead of concatenating the values into the SQL statement.  It can leave your code vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: yes i know but just try how to insert null or empty rows i click button

Answer (score 0):

That's most probably cause you have a primary key as `@@IDENTITY` column and thus you need to specify all the column explicitly

```
insert into hhh(col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES('" +
```

Again your code vulnerable to *SQL Injection*. Use parameterized query and see [Preventing SQL injection on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818473/preventing-sql-injection-on-insert)