# invalid SQL statement error when trying to input data into access file on C# program

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I put the code into SSMS and it underlines red for the first + sign on the first line and the `PatientID` next to `Convert.ToInt32`. the code is large so I'm only posting half of it since the error is on the first line.

```
"if not exists (select PatientID from patienttable where PatientID = " + PatientID.Text +  ") begin INSERT INTO patienttable VALUES (" + Convert.ToInt32(PatientID.Text) + "','" + OldID.Text + "','" 
                    + PtLastName.Text 
                    + "','" + PtPreviousLastName.Text + "','" + PtFirstName.Text + 
                    "','" + HomeAddress1.Text + "','" 
                    + HomeAddress2.Text + "','" + HomeCity.Text
                    + "','" + HomeStateProvinceRegion.Text + "','" 
                    + HomeZip.Text + "','" + Country.Text + "','" 
                    + Citizenship.Text + "','" + PtHomePhone.Text + "','"
                    + EmergencyPhoneNumber.Text + "','" +
                     PtHomeFax.Text+  "','"  +Pager.Text+ "','" + EmailAddress.Text 
                    + "','" + PtSS.Text + "','" 
                    + DOB.Text + "','" + Gender.Text + "','"
                    + EthnicAssociation.Text + "','" + Religion.Text + EthnicAssociation.Text + "','" + MaritalStatus.Text + "','"
                    + "','" + EmploymentStatus.Text + "','" + HospitalMR.Text + "','" + DateofExpire.Text + "','" + Referral.Text + "','" + CurrentPrimaryHCPId.Text + "','" + Specialist1.Text + "','" + Specialist2.Text + "','" + Specialist3.Text + "','" + Specialist4.Text + "','" + OriginalStaffHCP.Text + "','" + CurrentStaffHCP.Text +  "','" + Active.Checked + "','"
                    + Comments.Text + "','" + DateEntered.Text 
                    
                    + "','" + BusinessPhone.Text + "','" + BusinessFax.Text + "','" + SubscriberRelationship.Text + "','" + EmployerID.Text + "','" + NextOfKinID.Text + "','" + PtMiddleInitial.Text + "','" + NextOfKinRelationshipToPatient.Text + "','" + NoticeOfPracticePrivacy.Checked + "','" + NPPDate.Text + "','" + Suffix.Text + "')
```

Comment: Ummm.. SSMS doesn't understand C# code... so all the C# in here is flagged as invalid sql because it's not sql.  You have to convert the variables to whatever their content is as literals.

Comment: That's not SQL, that's a non-SQL string (SQL strings are delimited with single quotes).  SSMS can't digest that.  I'm assuming that this is really some C# code.  I'm also guessing that things line `PtFirstName.Text` refer to some sort of UI control's `Text` property.  You need to read up on **SQL Injection** vulnerabilities.  At the very least you need to be using SQL Parameters, not string concatenation to build your query

Comment: You had **just asked** the very same question only 2 hours ago, and it was closed - so please **DO NOT** repost the same question over and over and over again - it will be closed over and over again (since it's still a duplicate of preivously answered questions here on SO)

Comment: Can you show us how you attempted to apply my recommendations from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818473/preventing-sql-injection-on-insert ?